# mysql C# syntax issue with a select statement

Tags: mysql, syntax

Hi I would like some help with my SQL syntax i'm very stumped into how to alter it to show the following Id,Author,Title From books

```
public  Book    getBookByID(int bookID) 
{   
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Attempting    to  get book    with    ID: "   +   bookID);    
      try   
      { 
          conn  =   new MySqlConnection(cs);    
          conn.Open();

          string stm = ("SELECT Id, AuthorId,Title  FROM    books   WHERE   Id  =   " + bookID);    
          MySqlCommand  cmd =   new MySqlCommand(stm,   conn);  
          rdr   =   cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And I recieve this error

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL    syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT   Id, AuthorId,Title  FROM    books   WHERE   Id  =   1' at line 1

Comment: what is the data type of ID ?

Comment: int(11) not null primary key auto-increment

Comment: try removing the spaces within the query something like `"SELECT Id, AuthorId,Title FROM books WHERE Id="+bookID`

Comment: Thanks that has removed the syntax error now the issues is with the debug output not showing what i'm selecting @AbhikChakraborty any idea this is the output// Attempting to get book with ID: 1            Then connector tests run and "The thread '<No Name>' (0x1880) has exited with code 0 (0x0)." for every row of data i have in books.

Comment: Well I dont know c# but since u tagged as mysql so i came to see if I can do something :)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Sorry i just realized my output was structured very horribly thank you for your help.